# Preserving Custom Date Index/Column after aggregating Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, aggregate

I am attempting to aggregate a pandas dataframe of daily data based on a `datetime64[ns]` column that it contains. Specifically, I am trying to get some statistics based on each week within the data (it doesn't matter where the week is defined to start, though knowing/setting that would also be nice).

My data is this,

[image]

, with my aggregating code being

```
grouped=mergedFinal.groupby(mergedFinal['DATE'].map(lambda x:x.week)).agg('mean')
```

The output I get, however, is missing the data each group is aggregated by, which is usually included if you aggregate by a categorical value:

[image]

Date `1`,`2`,`3`,etc doesn't tell me anything, even if the aggregation is running correctly.

So how would I perform this while displaying the weeks data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `resample`:

```
 df.resample('W', on='DATE').mean()
```

MCVE:

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE':pd.date_range('2018-01-03',periods=30),'USD1':np.random.random(30)})

df.resample('W',on='DATE').mean()
```

Output:

```
                USD1
DATE                
2018-01-07  0.496049
2018-01-14  0.576283
2018-01-21  0.360541
2018-01-28  0.628077
2018-02-04  0.378686
```

Comment: So, if I am analyzing these results correctly, it will use the last calendar date of a week when choosing a date to display? Would I be able to fiddle around with how the displayed week is chosen (other days, diff. string output, etc)?

Comment: Yes, it is defaulting to Sunday, I think, but you could W-Wednesday, or W-Saturday to change which day of the week to start on.